# How to get same results for UPDATE query at MS Access and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

While moving back-end from Access `.mdb` file to SQL Server, the following problem was discovered.

If you join two tables `A` and `B` and there are several rows in `A` for one row in `B` Access sequentially updates target row in `B` with each rows of `A`. SQL Server acts differently (and as written in manual): target row in `B` is updated by one random row of `A`.

For MS Access

```
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE A (id int, valA real);"
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE B (id int, valB real);" 
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (1, 1);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (1, 2);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (1, 3);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (2, 1);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (2, 2);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (3, 0);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into B(id, valB) VALUES (1, 0);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into B(id, valB) VALUES (2, 0);"
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into B(id, valB) VALUES (3, 0);"
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id SET B.valB = B.valB + A.valA;"
docmd.OpenTable "B"
```

Access result:

```
id  valB
1   6
2   3
3   0
```

For SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int, valA real);
insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0);
CREATE TABLE B (id int, valB real);
insert into B(id, valB) VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0);
UPDATE B SET B.valB = B.valB + A.valA  
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id ;
SELECT * FROM B;
```

SQL Server result

```
id  valB
1   1
2   1
3   0
```

I need to get MS Access results in SQL Server. For this small and easy query it is possible to correct command in this way

```
UPDATE B 
SET B.valB = B.valB + AA.valA 
FROM (SELECT SUM(valA) as valA, id 
      FROM A GROUP BY id) AS AA 
INNER JOIN B ON AA.id = B.id ;
```

But I have 150 update queries with 3 to 5 joined tables and it's hard to write parser which could fix them.

There are even such queries to write count of lines in `A` to `B.valB`, and it works well in Access, but sets `B.valB = 1` at SQL server

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id SET B.valB = B.valB + 1;
```

Typical four tables query :

```
 UPDATE 
     vrtReserved
 SET 
    vrtReserved.qtyOutput = Round([vrtReserved].[qtyOutput] + [ComplexRes].[Qty], 3)
 FROM 
    Complex
     INNER JOIN ((vrtReserved
     INNER JOIN ComplexRes ON (vrtReserved.Code = ComplexRes.Code) AND (vrtReserved.UE = ComplexRes.UE))
     INNER JOIN ComplexDetail ON (vrtReserved.flagDAV = ComplexDetail.flagDAV) AND (ComplexRes.CodeComplDetail = ComplexDetail.CodeComplDetail)) ON (vrtReserved.CodeBox = Complex.CodeBox) AND (Complex.CodeCompl = ComplexDetail.CodeCompl) AND (Complex.CodeCompl = ComplexRes.CodeCompl);
```

Must be rewritten to

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT vrtReserved.CodeBox, vrtReserved.Code, vrtReserved.UE, vrtReserved.flagDAV, Sum(ComplexRes.Qty) AS [Sum-Qty]
    FROM Complex INNER JOIN ((vrtReserved INNER JOIN ComplexRes ON (vrtReserved.UE = ComplexRes.UE) AND (vrtReserved.Code = ComplexRes.Code)) INNER JOIN ComplexDetail ON (ComplexRes.CodeComplDetail = ComplexDetail.CodeComplDetail) AND (vrtReserved.flagDAV = ComplexDetail.flagDAV)) ON (Complex.CodeCompl = ComplexDetail.CodeCompl) AND (Complex.CodeCompl = ComplexRes.CodeCompl) AND (Complex.CodeBox = vrtReserved.CodeBox)
    GROUP BY vrtReserved.CodeBox, vrtReserved.Code, vrtReserved.UE, vrtReserved.flagDAV, vrtReserved.qtyOutput
)
UPDATE 
     vrtReserved
SET 
    vrtReserved.qtyOutput = Round([vrtReserved].[qtyOutput] + [Sum-Qty], 3)
FROM 
    vrtReserved
    INNER JOIN
    CTE 
    ON (vrtReserved.Code = CTE.Code) AND (vrtReserved.UE = CTE.UE) AND (vrtReserved.flagDAV = CTE.flagDAV) AND (vrtReserved.CodeBox = CTE.CodeBox);
```

Is there any other way except manual correction of query's text to reproduce MS Access results at SQL Server?

Comment: What happens if you run your original Access UPDATE query on linked SQL Server tables?

Comment: If i use original Access Update Query on linked SQL Server tables i get results same as on pure Access. But some queries take too long to complete(more than on pure access)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you won't find anything to make this transition automatic. It's different database engines, and you will have to adapt the code. -- This doesn't help you now, but these queries should have used `SUM()` from the start. Using `+` to sum rows in a JOIN sounds adventurous, to put it mildly.

Comment: And if you are forced to make significant changes anyway, you should think about this: Is it really necessary to store calculated values in tables? Normally, your `CTE` expression should be a VIEW. It does the calculation, and you can use its output wherever you want, there should be no need to store them in another table. And having to update them all the time.

Comment: *manual correction of query's text* ... where is this correction being made? Also, what is wrong with second query solution with CTE?

Comment: @Andre, Parfait, this is big legacy application there are 1412 `UPDATE` queries and 730 of them have `JOIN` . I have to move Back-End to SQL server. I have written VBA module that converts Jet-SQL to T-SQL and now only two problems still exist: 1. this usage of Jet Engine special power to semi update the same record and 2. usage of `.Refresh` methods in Forms.

Comment: Are you expecting a non-SQL solution (i.e., avoid re-writing *any* query) to render SQL server's `UPDATE` on multiple `JOIN` equivalent to MS Access? In other words, you are asking to match two different SQL dialects for same results without any SQL changes?

Comment: @Partfait several problems during migration were solved by changing various settings. So I wish either 'magic' settings to solve this problem too or some variant of solution that could be used to code automatic translation.  Cte or window function or group by queries require too much parsing. So maybe there is some other way.

Comment: Having a function that automagically converts Access SQL update queries to single T-SQL queries is likely not feasible. The sample query shared here is still simple, but for example multi-table update queries (if you update columns from more than just one table) can't be reproduced in a single T-SQL query.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth you are right. But fortunately i don't need to do transformation for full syntax. My module must process only that cases that used in application. And multi-table updates in most cases can be automatically replaced with several queries (if there is no side effects in assignments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some limitations and assumptions this code work well with queries in my database

```
Public Function UpSizeUPDATEwithJOIN(tsqlText As String, Optional fMultiLineOutput As Boolean) As String
' transform TSQL UPDATE with JOINS and repeatable self assigments to UPDATE with CTE, GROUP BY and SUM
' test commands
'?UpSizeUPDATEwithJOIN("UPDATE B SET B.valB = B.valB + A.valA FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id ;",true)
'?UpSizeUPDATEwithJOIN("UPDATE vrtРезерв SET vrtРезерв.КвоВыдано = Round([vrtРезерв].[КвоВыдано]+[КомплектРез].[Кво],3.0), vrtРезерв.ДолгВыдать = vrtРезерв.ДолгВыдать - [КомплектДет].[Списано] FROM Комплект INNER JOIN ((vrtРезерв INNER JOIN КомплектРез ON (vrtРезерв.Код = КомплектРез.Код) AND (vrtРезерв.ВЭ = КомплектРез.ВЭ)) INNER JOIN КомплектДет ON (vrtРезерв.przDav = КомплектДет.przDav) AND (КомплектРез.КодКомплДет = КомплектДет.КодКомплДет)) ON (vrtРезерв.КодКор = Комплект.КодКор) AND (Комплект.КодКомпл = КомплектДет.КодКомпл) AND (Комплект.КодКомпл = КомплектРез.КодКомпл);",true)

    Dim tmpSQL As String

    Dim nameTargetTable As String
    Dim enameTargetTable As String
    Dim cLenTableEName As Long
    Dim cLenTableName As Long
    Dim strNL As String

    If fMultiLineOutput Then
        strNL = vbNewLine
    End If

    nameTargetTable = unWrapWith(Trim(GetInner(tsqlText, "UPDATE ", " SET")), "[", "]") ' table
    enameTargetTable = wrapWith(nameTargetTable, "[", "]")                              ' [table]
    cLenTableEName = Len(enameTargetTable)
    cLenTableName = Len(nameTargetTable)

    Dim tsqlFROMpart As String
    Dim dictGROUPBYFields As Dictionary

    tsqlFROMpart = GetInnerEx(tsqlText, "FROM ", "WHERE ", ";", """", "<EOL>")
    Set dictGROUPBYFields = New Dictionary
    dictGROUPBYFields.CompareMode = TextCompare ' means Table = TaBlE

    Dim posAt As Long
    Dim posStart As Long
    Dim posEnd As Long
    Dim strConditions As String
    Dim arrConditions() As String
    Dim strCurrCond As String
    Dim strParts() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim nameField As String
    Dim nameTable As String
    Dim posTableNameSt As Long
    Dim posTableNameEnd As Long

    ' join conditions start at ON
    posAt = InStr(1, tsqlFROMpart, " ON ")

    While posAt > 0
        posStart = posAt + 4
        ' conditions last till JOIN or end of FROM part
        posEnd = FirstAnyOf(tsqlFROMpart, posStart, " LEFT ## RIGHT ## INNER ## JOIN ## ON ", "##")

        strConditions = Mid(tsqlFROMpart, posStart, posEnd - posStart + 1)
        ' conditions separated by AND or OR logical operators
        strConditions = Replace(strConditions, " AND ", "##")
        strConditions = Replace(strConditions, " OR ", "##")
        arrConditions = Split(strConditions, "##")

        For i = LBound(arrConditions) To UBound(arrConditions)
            strCurrCond = arrConditions(i)
            ' condition can be made by = , < , > , <> , >= , <=
            strCurrCond = Replace(strCurrCond, "=", "##")
            strCurrCond = Replace(strCurrCond, ">", "##")
            strCurrCond = Replace(strCurrCond, "<", "##")
            strCurrCond = Replace(strCurrCond, "####", "##")
            strCurrCond = unWrapWith(strCurrCond, "(", ")")

            strParts = Split(strCurrCond, "##")

            ' target table can be on left side or right side
            For j = 0 To 1
                strParts(j) = Trim(strParts(j))
                strParts(j) = Replace(strParts(j), "(", "") ' becase cutting
                strParts(j) = Replace(strParts(j), ")", "") ' is not accurate

                ' name in this condition can be wrapped with [] or unwrapped
                posTableNameSt = InStr(1, strParts(j), enameTargetTable)
                If posTableNameSt <> 0 Then
                    posTableNameEnd = posTableNameSt + cLenTableEName
                Else
                    posTableNameSt = InStr(1, strParts(j), nameTargetTable)
                    posTableNameEnd = posTableNameSt + cLenTableName
                End If

                If posTableNameSt > 0 Then
                    ' found , so add to dictionary
                    nameField = Mid(strParts(j), posTableNameEnd + 1) ' +1 because of . between table name and field name
                    dictGROUPBYFields(nameField) = strParts(j)
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j
        Next i

        posAt = InStr(posAt + 1, tsqlFROMpart, " ON ")
    Wend

    Dim tsqlSETpart As String
    tsqlSETpart = GetInner(tsqlText, " SET ", " FROM ")

    Dim arrSetExpressions() As String
    Dim strCurrExpression As String
    Dim strExprValue As String
    Dim dictFieldsInExpressions As Dictionary
    Dim posFieldNameEnd As Long
    Dim dictTmp As Dictionary
    Dim posEqualSign As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim tsqlNewSETpart As String

    Set dictFieldsInExpressions = New Dictionary
    dictFieldsInExpressions.CompareMode = TextCompare ' means Table.Fld = TaBlE.FlD

    arrSetExpressions = SplitLineCall("SET " & tsqlSETpart)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSetExpressions) ' skipped SET element
        strCurrExpression = arrSetExpressions(i) ' whole part
        posEqualSign = InStr(1, strCurrExpression, "=")
        strExprValue = Trim(Mid(strCurrExpression, posEqualSign + 1))

        ' so look in expressions for table.field references and put them into dictionary if not from target table
        posAt = InStr(1, strExprValue, ".")
        While posAt > 0
            ' go right to find fields name
            If Mid(strExprValue, posAt + 1, 1) = "[" Then
                posFieldNameEnd = InStr(posAt + 2, strExprValue, "]")
            Else
                posFieldNameEnd = FirstAnyOf(strExprValue, posAt + 2, " #,#;#""#)#(#=#+#-#/#*")
            End If
            nameField = Mid(strExprValue, posAt + 1, posFieldNameEnd - posAt)

            'go left to find table name
            If Mid(strExprValue, posAt - 1, 1) = "]" Then
                posTableNameSt = InStrRev(strExprValue, "[", posAt - 2)
            Else
                posTableNameSt = FirstAnyOfRev(strExprValue, posAt - 1, " #,#;#""#)#(#=#+#-#/#*") + 1
            End If
            nameTable = Mid(strExprValue, posTableNameSt, posAt - posTableNameSt)

            ' if we found not target table add to dictionary
            If unWrapWith(nameTable, "[", "]") <> nameTargetTable Then
                strTmp = Mid(strExprValue, posTableNameSt, posFieldNameEnd - posTableNameSt + 1)
                If isEvaluationable(strTmp) Then
                    ' do nothing it is just a number with point
                Else
                    Set dictTmp = New Dictionary
                    dictTmp("nameTable") = nameTable
                    dictTmp("nameField") = nameField
                    dictTmp("expression") = strTmp

                    Set dictFieldsInExpressions(dictTmp("expression")) = dictTmp
                    Set dictTmp = Nothing

                    ' and replace Table name to CTE
                    strExprValue = Left(strExprValue, posTableNameSt - 1) & "CTE" & Mid(strExprValue, posAt)
                    posAt = posAt + Len(nameTable) - 3
                End If
            End If

            posAt = InStr(posAt + 1, strExprValue, ".")
        Wend
        strCurrExpression = Left(strCurrExpression, posEqualSign) & " " & strExprValue
        arrSetExpressions(i) = strCurrExpression  ' write back
        tsqlNewSETpart = tsqlNewSETpart & " , " & strNL & strCurrExpression
    Next i
    tsqlNewSETpart = Mid(tsqlNewSETpart, 4 + Len(strNL))

    Dim tsqlResult As String
    Dim tsqlNewFROMpart As String ' 1
    Dim tsqlNewONpart As String '7
    Dim tsqlGROUPfields As String ' 2 & 6
    Dim tsqlSUMfields As String
    Dim tsqlWHEREpart As String

    tsqlNewFROMpart = GetInner(tsqlText, " FROM ", ";", True)
    tsqlWHEREpart = GetInnerEx(tsqlNewFROMpart, "WHERE ", "GROUP BY ", "HAVING ", "ORDER BY ", ";", "<EOL>")

    If tsqlWHEREpart <> "" Then
        tsqlWHEREpart = " WHERE " & tsqlWHEREpart
    End If

    tsqlGROUPfields = Join(dictGROUPBYFields.Items, " , ")

    Dim varKey As Variant
    Dim dictItem As Variant

    For Each dictItem In dictFieldsInExpressions.Items
        tsqlSUMfields = tsqlSUMfields & ", " & "SUM(" & dictItem("expression") & ") AS " & dictItem("nameField") & ""
    Next dictItem

    For Each varKey In dictGROUPBYFields.Keys
        tsqlNewONpart = tsqlNewONpart & " AND " & "(" & enameTargetTable & "." & varKey & " = CTE." & varKey & ")"
    Next varKey
    tsqlNewONpart = Mid(tsqlNewONpart, 6)

    tsqlResult = _
                "WITH CTE AS (" & strNL & _
                "  SELECT " & strNL & _
                "           " & tsqlGROUPfields & strNL & _
                "           " & tsqlSUMfields & strNL & _
                "  FROM " & strNL & _
                "         " & tsqlNewFROMpart & strNL & _
                "  GROUP BY " & strNL & _
                "             " & tsqlGROUPfields & strNL & _
                ") " & strNL & _
                "UPDATE " & strNL & _
                "    " & enameTargetTable & " " & strNL & _
                "SET " & strNL & _
                "" & tsqlNewSETpart & " " & strNL & _
                "FROM " & strNL & _
                "    " & enameTargetTable & " " & strNL & _
                "     INNER JOIN " & strNL & _
                "    CTE " & strNL & _
                "     ON " & strNL & _
                "          " & tsqlNewONpart & strNL & _
                "" & tsqlWHEREpart & strNL & _
                ";"

    If Not fMultiLineOutput Then
        tsqlResult = ReplaceAll(tsqlResult, "  ", " ")
    End If

    Dim bIsResultValid As Boolean
    'bIsResultValid = isValidTSQL(tsqlResult) ' check if we got goot TSQL
    'If bIsResultValid Then
        UpSizeUPDATEwithJOIN = """" & tsqlResult & """"
    'Else
    '    UpSizeUPDATEwithJOIN = tsqlText
    '    Debug.Print , "!!U GOT bad: " & tsqlResult
    'End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting observation! Likely, MS Access updates multiple times for each join match rendering a cumulative sum update whereas SQL Server updates only once on the **first** instance of each join match.

Consider using a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to stay at unit level and avoid the aggregate subquery:

```
UPDATE B 
SET B.valB = B.valB + t.cum_sum
FROM B
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.valA) OVER(PARTITION BY A.id) AS cum_sum
   FROM A
   INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID) t   
ON B.ID = t.ID;
```

Or with a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS 
  (
   SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.valA) OVER(PARTITION BY A.id) AS cum_sum
   FROM A
   INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID  
  )

UPDATE B 
SET B.valB = B.valB + CTE.cum_sum
FROM B
INNER JOIN CTE 
ON B.ID = CTE.ID;
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/SLKH91793)

Comment: OP, I noticed you just opened a bounty but never asked a follow-up to this window function solution posted well over a month ago. Please advise why this did not work for your needs. You can run it as a pass-through query in MS Access.

Comment: window function or CTE are not suitable because this way requires manual correction, but the question was how to get it automatically. The question included modified T-SQL for simple query initially.

Comment: @4dmonster what you mean **requires manual correction** ? are you asking ** how to get the same result ** or are you asking, how to convert ms access sql to mssql now? just rewite the 150 queries and get over with migration :) 1/2 days job

Comment: @krishKM how to get same results by manual rewriting is written in question. I wonder if there are settings or easy-to-program transformation of source Jet-SQL to T-SQL. And there are 730 UPDATE queries with `JOIN`.

Comment: question asked 1 month ago. Transforming 25 queries a day would have forecasted estimated completion date as today. Sadly, there is no magical way of doing this unless you want to keep the ACCESS and run it via access engine. I'd recommend start converting one by one in parallel to your "searching for your magic way"

Comment: @krishKM this was background task, it will be started next week. And certainly if there is no other suitable way except manual rewriting it will be solved by manual rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the order TSQL seems to use the first value.  This is non-deterministic as a table is not supposed to have a natural order.

```
declare @a table (id int, val int)
insert into @a(id, val) VALUES  (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0);
declare @b table (id int, val int);
insert into @b (id, val) VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0);
UPDATE b SET b.val = b.val + a.val  
FROM @a  a
INNER JOIN @b b
   ON a.id = b.id 
SELECT * FROM @b;
```

Not a lot of help you you could create views for sum and count to not repeat as much code.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can found is:

```
create table A (id int, valA real)
insert into A(id, valA) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0)
create table B (id int, valB real)
insert into B(id, valB) VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)

UPDATE B SET B.valB += (SELECT SUM(valA) FROM A WHERE A.id=B.id)

select * from B
```

as Microsoft says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#best-practices) and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#n-using-the-update-statement-with-information-from-another-table),

> *a single UPDATE statement never updates the same row two times.*